SPA workloop engine works on Firefox and not on Chrome
I have been building a SPA library/engine to help me with my work for a project. I have implemented a structure slightly to the React SPA engine. The problem I have is that the engine correctly works on firefox, if I add a console.log() within the loop I can it triggers a lot. However on Chrome, I have no trigger, and I need to interact with the browser for the workloop to get some triggers and rendering.
This is the loop :
  workLoop(deadline) {
    console.log('workLoop');
    let shouldYield = false
    while (this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork() && !shouldYield) {
      this.stateManager.setNextUnitOfWork(this.reconciler.performUnitOfWork(
        this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork()
      ));
      shouldYield = deadline.timeRemaining() < 1
    }

    if (!this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork() && this.stateManager.getWorkInProgressRoot()) {
      this.commitRoot()
    }

  window.requestIdleCallback(this.workLoop)
}

I tried to remove the deadline, however it seems to not change the problem and cause others.
I noticed that when I use browser navigation arrow back enough time, until I hit chrome default start page, then back in the apps, the app freezes that way. However if I open a fresh browser window, this doesn't happen. I noticed also that requestIdleCallback fires up only when I interact with the page on Chrome while it fires up all the time in Firefox !

I found a solution. The problem seems linked to chrome agressively trying to keep the tab in a idle state unless there is some user interaction like scrolling or clicking. They must do this in order to preserve RAM usage or battery life. The optimization is so agressive that even settings save battery or other performance saving option to false didn't fix anything.
So I rebuild the core engine with a very agressive loop based on requestAnimationFrame !
aggressiveIdleCallback(callback, options = { timeout: 100 }) {
  const tick = () => {
    const deadline = {
      didTimeout: false,
      timeRemaining: () => Infinity
    };
    callback(deadline);  // Run the passed workLoop with simulated deadline object
    setTimeout(() => window.requestAnimationFrame(tick), options.timeout); // Recur at specified timeout
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

workLoop(deadline) {
  console.log('workLoop');
  let shouldYield = false;
  while (this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork() && !shouldYield) {
    this.stateManager.setNextUnitOfWork(this.reconciler.performUnitOfWork(
      this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork()
    ));
    shouldYield = deadline.timeRemaining() <= 1 || deadline.didTimeout;
  }

  if (!this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork() && this.stateManager.getWorkInProgressRoot()) {
    this.commitRoot();
  }

  // Only schedule new work if there's more to do
  if (this.stateManager.getNextUnitOfWork()) {
    this.aggressiveIdleCallback(this.workLoop);
  } else {
    console.log("No more work. Idle now.");
  }
}

